# Chroot vs Singularity

Tags: containers, chroot, singularity-container

I just started using Singularity containers. I found that no cgroup is used. We can see the processus of host. I wonder it is the same as chroot. Am I correct? What is the advantages of Singularity apart its simplicity to create containers?

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite good FAQ section on the Singularity Website that could answer your questions:

> I wonder it is the same as chroot. Am I correct?

[This is answered here.](http://singularity.lbl.gov/faq#how-is-singularity-different-from-chroot) Among others it says that you cannot utilize kernel namespaces, manage bind points, etc. with chroot.

> What is the advantages of Singularity apart its simplicity to create containers?

The advantage of Singularity is that is more suitable for HPC systems. Singularity seems to be more secure than Docker for HPC. When executing a container, the user in the container is the same as on the 'normal' HPC system.

Job scheduler can handle Singularity containe, because running a Singularity container is like executing a 'normal' command. For me it was also no problem to run GPU jobs with singularity containers.

You could also post your question in the Singularity [user group.](https://groups.google.com/a/lbl.gov/forum/#!forum/singularity)